# Parallel Processing Python : Why parallel processing is slower than serial processing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to use parallel processing on my list , which have this format :

```
[ (key , { three values } )]
```

I want to group those keys which have any similar values :

example :  `[ (1 , { 22,31,21 } ) , (2, {19,98,11}) , (3, {1,22,4})]`

Expected output : `(1,3) because { 22,31,21 }.intersection({1,22,4} ) have 22`

Now I am benchmarking it with nested loop vs parallel processing :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from tqdm import tqdm
```

> by parallel processing :

```
def check_values(value):
    result=[]
    for j in fake_data:
        if len(value[1].intersection(j[1]))!=0:
            if j[0]!=value[0]:
                result.append((value[0],j[0]))
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":

    agents= 5
    chunksize=1

    with Pool(processes=agents) as pool:
        result=pool.map(check_values,fake_data,chunksize)

datar=[tuple(sorted(j)) for i in result for j in i]
print(len(sorted(set(datar))))
```

> By nested loop {serial processing } :

```
def without_pool():
    datar=[]

    for ivalue in tqdm(fake_data):
        for jvalue in fake_data:
            if len(ivalue[1].intersection(jvalue[1]))!=0:
                if ivalue[0]!=jvalue[0]:
                    datar.append((ivalue[0],jvalue[0]))
    return datar

sorted_result=[tuple(sorted(i)) for i in without_pool()]
print(len(sorted(set(sorted_result))))
```

I am expecting faster execution in parallel method but i am getting slower speed in parallel and fast speed in serial method , Am i doing wrong somewhere please suggest:

Here is [notebook file](https://files.fm/u/3rajzr4p) which have data and all the code , You can run it :

Comment: notebooks are notoriously bad at multiprocessing. Try running this on terminal and see what happens.

Comment: It should be much faster if you use default `chunksize`.

Comment: @Sraw what is default chunksize ?

Comment: Just leave it blank `result=pool.map(check_values, fake_data)`

Comment: @Sraw but how it will choose chunksize ? What is deafult one ?

Comment: It is `len(iterable) / (len(processes) * 4 )`

Comment: @Sraw but it's taking more time if i am giving default chunksize.